# Validating a form with ajax json response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am sending a form to the server but before sending the form I make an ajax request that returns a json response.  The problem is, if a condition is valid I ask to the user if they still want to send the form, but it always sends the form even if the user says no.

This is my code

```
$("#form-alta-servicios").submit(function(){
if( confirm('Desea enviar la informacion ahora?') )
{
  //entonces validamos datos
  if( $('#tel').val()=='')
  {
    alert('Ingresa el numero de telefono');
    $('#tel').focus()
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    if( $('#dir').val()== '' )
    {
      alert('La direccion es un dato requerido');
      $("#dir").focus();
      return false;
    }
    else
    {
      if( $("#taxi_id option:selected").val()=='0' )
      {
        alert('Seleccione un taxi por favor');
        return false;
      }
      else
      {
        $.ajax(
        {
          type: 'GET',
          url: '/verifica-si/'+$("#taxi_id option:selected").val()+'/servicio',              
          data: {},              
          success: function(data)
          {
            if(data['msj']=='encontrado')
            {
              if(confirm('Existe un servicio, desea terminarlo y empezar uno nuevo'))
              {
                return true;
              }
              else
              {
                return false;
              }
            }
          },
          dataType: 'json'          
        });   //fin solicitud ajax       
      }
    }
  }
}
else
{
  return false;
}
```

});

The part that I do the question is

```
success: function(data)
          {
            if(data['msj']=='encontrado')
            {
              if(confirm('Existe un servicio, desea terminarlo y empezar uno nuevo'))
              {
                return true;
              }
              else
              {
                return false;
              }
            }
          },
```

If confirm is true it must send the form, but if is false it must stop sending the form, but it still sending it.

Comment: 2 problems, ajax is asynchronous so validation code won't wait for it to complete. Also return from `success` doesn't return to the outer function, it really does nothing

Comment: very helpful comment. I am newbie. Thank you.